# App getting hang at semaphore_wait_trap in xCode 7.0

Tags: ios9, xcode7, dismiss, presentviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a ViewController on button click. Dismiss ViewController on clicking back button in new ViewController.

It work's fine for the first time. When I restart the app again and try to use that Back button app get's hang at "semaphore_wait_trap" on main_thread.

For the first time I'm showing LoginViewController, but when app is restarted and if user is already login then I'm redirecting to DashBoardViewController.

I'm unable to find the cause. Please help me if you have any idea about it.